# How to declare many variables?

Tags: python

Here is the letters:

```
letters='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
```

I made a list of it with this:

```
chars=[]
for i in letters:
  chars.append(i)
```

So I have a chars list.

I need to all `variables=0` each one to declare. And I wrote that:

```
for i in chars:
  chars[i]=0;
```

But there is an error message, like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 15, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The question: How to declare these multiple variables?

Comment: `for i in chars`, loops through the *items* in the list, not the indices, which causes you to index a list with a letter, not an integer.  You probably want, `for i, e in enumerate(chars)`

Comment: I think the root problem here is that you want a dict, not a list. Like this: `chars = {}`. Then `for i in letters: chars[i] = 0`.

Comment: Or, if your goal is to count up something per letter, maybe you just wanted [`chars = collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Or, even better, you might even be able to let the `Counter` do all the counting, like `chars = collections.Counter(input_string)`.

Comment: I suggest that you work through one or two more tutorials on aggregate data types: list, dict, and string in particular.  I'm not clear on what you want to do, but the way you've tried to do it suggests that things will be *much* easier with a different data structure.

Comment: Why are you trying to set 62 variables to 0?  What is the final program supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either a list of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) or a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). A simple solution to do it:

```
>>> import string
>>> letters = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
>>> chars = dict.fromkeys(letters , 0)
>>> chars
>>> {...'a': 0, 'b': 0 ....}
```

To use list of tuples:

```
>>> list(chars.items())
>>> [...('a',0), ('b', 0)...]
```

Answer (score 1):

### The Solution

So, in short, what you want is a dictionary (mapping) of `character -> 0` for each character in the input.

This is the way to do it:

```
letters='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
chars = {char: 0 for char in letters}
```

### The Problem

The problem with the original code was that there, `chars` was a `list` (because it was created as a list here: `chars=[]`), and characters were used as its indices.

So, the first time `chars[i]=0;` was executed (BTW, `;` is not needed here), `i` was `'A'` and `chars['A']=0` produces the error.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `list` comprehensions is to use `map`

```
In [841]: letters='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'

In [842]: chars = list(map(lambda l: 0, letters))
```

Or if you want a `dict` like the other answers are suggesting

```
In [844]: dict(map(lambda l: (l, 0), letters))
```

I generally find `list`/`dict` comprehensions to both be faster and more readable (to me at least). This is just a different approach

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create `0`-list with the length of string `letters`.

```
letters='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
chars = [0 for _ in range(len(letters))]
```

Comment: [ 0 for x in letters ]

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
letters='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'

# dict comprehension
dd = { x:0 for x in list(letters)}; dd
{'A': 0,
 'B': 0,
 'C': 0,
 'D': 0,
 'E': 0,
 'F': 0,
 'G': 0,
 'H': 0,
 'I': 0,
 'J': 0,
 'K': 0,
 'L': 0,
 'M': 0,
 'N': 0,
 'O': 0,
 'P': 0,
 'Q': 0,
 'R': 0,
 'S': 0,
 'T': 0,
 'U': 0,
 'V': 0,
 'W': 0,
 'X': 0,
 'Y': 0,
 'Z': 0,
 'a': 0,
 'b': 0,
 'c': 0,
 'd': 0,
 'e': 0,
 'f': 0,
 'g': 0,
 'h': 0,
 'i': 0,
 'j': 0,
 'k': 0,
 'l': 0,
 'm': 0,
 'n': 0,
 'o': 0,
 'p': 0,
 'q': 0,
 'r': 0,
 's': 0,
 't': 0,
 'u': 0,
 'v': 0,
 'w': 0,
 'x': 0,
 'y': 0,
 'z': 0,
 '0': 0,
 '1': 0,
 '2': 0,
 '3': 0,
 '4': 0,
 '5': 0,
 '6': 0,
 '7': 0,
 '8': 0,
 '9': 0}
```

update:

```
dd['A'] = 13
dd
dd{'A': 13,
 'B': 0,
 'C': 0,
 'D': 0,
 'E': 0,
 'F': 0,
 'G': 0,
 'H': 0,
 'I': 0,
```

Or,

```
list(letters) 
['A',
 'B',
 'C',
 'D',
 'E',
 'F',
 'G',
 'H',
 'I',
 'J',
 'K',
 'L',
 'M',
 'N',
 'O',
 'P',
 'Q',
 'R',
 'S',
 'T',
 'U',
 'V',
 'W',
 'X',
 'Y',
 'Z',
 'a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'e',
 'f',
 'g',
 'h',
 'i',
 'j',
 'k',
 'l',
 'm',
 'n',
 'o',
 'p',
 'q',
 'r',
 's',
 't',
 'u',
 'v',
 'w',
 'x',
 'y',
 'z',
 '0',
 '1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 '7',
 '8',
 '9']
```