# Python and Variable Assignment

Tags: python, variables

This is just a question and I don't have any example code. But let's say that you were to make a python program were you have a "star" variable the star variable holds an integer and that integer is the age of the star, each time the program loops it adds a value of 1 to the star variable and if the star variable is equal to 100 it will create a new star which has its variable and the same process will occur with this variable as well.

How would you create a whole new variable or something along these lines without assigning one while writing the program?

Comment: Good (albeit poorly-researched) question. Use a data structure of some sort. Any programming tutorial in any language should introduce such things sooner rather than later.

Comment: After I chose a different closure reason, I found the duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887012/how-to-declare-many-variables

Comment: @Prune OP's question seems more basic than the question that you link to. In that question a dictionary is the natural choice. In this question, they seem to be unaware of the existence (or perhaps purpose of) simple lists.

Comment: The various answers include list, tuple, dict, and map usage.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the object in a list. As a new star is created, just append it.

Comment: But the value in the object doesn't change

Comment: @Userz - Then create an object, give me a minute and I will quickly make something

Comment: ok, sorry I am new to python