# Python function with "shape-shifting" variables

Tags: python

So, I was wondering if creating a function with variables that are changing names (but only partially) is possible. Here is an example:

```
def function(string):
    {string} + something = 1
    return {string} + something
```

So when I call it like:

```
function(test)
```

it returns variable called "testsomething" that equals 1.

Hope my question is understandable, is this even possible?

Comment: No, it's not. Why do you want to do something like this though? Maybe I could be helpful there.

Comment: Even if that worked, your function would be exactly equivalent to `return 1`.  The fact that the returned value was briefly held in a variable of a certain name is not a detail that's visible outside of the function.

Comment: I suspect that this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  How would the name of a local variable matter?  What is your interface such that the caller has any interest in this naming?  Somewhere, you're violating a basic principle of modularization.

Comment: @puppydog Actually I have few almost similar functions (only the variable names differ) which I run in a loop. All of them all yielding variables, and I need to identify them afterwards.

Comment: @Prune Actually I have few almost similar functions (only the variable names differ) which I run in a loop. All of them all yielding variables, and I need to identify them afterwards.

Comment: Ah. Then use @John Gordon's solution. You're looking for a dictionary.

Comment: In that case, this is a straightforward duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887012/how-to-declare-many-variables)

Comment: Another solution that my help is exec, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122345/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, if you put the variable inside a dictionary:

```
def function(name):
    mydict = {}
    mydict[name+"something"] = 1
    return mydict
```

Comment: Great! That is exactly what I need